# Unity cannot retrieve files from server on local network, connection fails?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, web, request

I'm setting up a multiplayer game where I need to save and load data inside of the Unity3D game from a server on my local area network. This data would be account information, scores, unlocks, etc. Pretty much all textual data.

It is local to my network mainly as a means of testing it out before or if it goes global.

The problem is that I cannot access the files I need to create or download from the local server from within the Unity application Play mode. I'm doing this inside of the editor, don't believe that makes a difference.

My setup is this: A Laptop running Unity - That same laptop temporarily acting as the server with a shared directory holding all of the data text files.

In my code, I link the URL to the directory on the server (laptop).

```
public static string path = "file://192.168.1.51/PINION/GAMEDATA/testing/userData.txt";
```

The IP is static so it does not change., and yes I know that will only work locally, which is what I'm trying to do right now.

In visual studio, if I control click the URL, it opens the user data file in notepad so I know the link is good. But when I run it in Unity with the code below, I get a "Cannot connect to destination host" error.

```
IEnumerator LoadingData(){string url = ServerMaster.path;

    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(url));

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    string[] pages = url.Split('/');
    int page = pages.Length - 1;

    if (request.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Network Error occurred. " + request.error); StopAllCoroutines();
    }
    else if (request.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log("HTTP Error occurred. " + request.error); StopAllCoroutines();
    }
    else
    {
        print("Download successful. " + pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
        print(request.downloadHandler.data.Length);
    }
}
```

I then run this bit of code which works fine which tells me the problem has to be with my LAN code.

```
IEnumerator LoadingData()
{
    string testURL = "https://www.google.com/";

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(testURL))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Get Request Completed!");
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine while my other code pointing to the local server continually fails. I'm new to this networking portion of Unity so I'm having a difficult time figuring this out.

Comment: The UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL method in the first example may be changing the name of the file in the url because it has a special character.

Comment: I tried without it and received an error with "Malformed URL"

Comment: Referencing [Unity's Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-for-local-files-on-android-failure.441655/). You may need three slashes after file like this. "file:///"